# I want to know how to execute my code in sequence in selenium web driver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
[testmethod]
public void abc()
{
}
[testmethod]
public void xyz()
{
}
[testmethod]
public void pqr()
{
}
```

I want to run in below sequence

```
xyz
abc
pqr
```

Currently it executes in a random order.

Comment: This is by design of your test framework. Why do you need them in an order?

Comment: what test framework?

Comment: Order should not matter.  Each test should be able to run independent of other tests.  Yeah, why is order important?

Comment: @Arran one testmethod is dependent on other.so if they don't execute in order it will fail.